# how to keep some characters using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I have this php code

```
$audio_name=preg_replace('/[&#].*[;]/','',$audio['name'][1][$i]);
```

but i want to keep the French characters

Comment: like the accent and the apostrophe...you know :D

Comment: Please show some example input and corresponding expected output

Comment: Give us an example of what you have and what you want it replaced with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), in the callback you can return `''` if you want to remove the element and return the matched element if you want to keep it.

Note: `.*` is greedy and will eat everything till the last `;`, so use `[^;]*`.

Answer (score 1):

for example, replacing AAAAAAAA  with BBBBBBBB:

```
$string= 'start AAAAAAAA end';
echo preg_replace('/(start)(.*?)(end)/i', (!empty('$1') ? '$1' : '').'BBBBBBBB'.(!empty('$2') ? '$2' : '') , $string);
```